# Amazon SES Email from EC2 - Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, actionmailer

I'm using Amazon SES to send email from a Ruby on Rails (version 3.2.3) app hosted on Amazon's EC2 infrastructure, and I'm getting repeated Timeouts while sending email.

```
Timeout::Error: execution expired
```

I do this using a delayed_job queue, and it fails several times before being successful (Some email addresses require up to 4 or 5 re-tries).

I have production access on Amazon SES. Any reason why these timeouts are happening? Do I need to apply to have my Amazon EC2 sending limitations removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, turns out you need to specifically request for EC2 mailing limitations to be removed to be able to send out mass email. This is the case even if you're using Amazon SES.

```
https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request
```

Once I applied to have these email sending limitations removed, they got back to me within a couple of hours and I was able to start sending email a lot smoothly.

Comment: As a complementary check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11196253/290343) which explains that you need to change the default port 25 to something else (say 587).